# HTML5 Player controlled by java-script not working at my homepage, is the code correct?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I found a script, which should prevent a link to redirect to the linked audiofile and instead give it to the HTML5 audio player above. I work in a web-editor where I can insert code. It doesn't seem to work though. Is there an error in the code I didn't find yet?

```
<script>
var audio;
var playlist;
var tracks;
var current;

init();
function init(){
    current = 0;
    audio = $('audio');
    playlist = $('#playlist');
    tracks = playlist.find('li a');
    len = tracks.length - 1;
    audio[0].volume = .10;
    playlist.find('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        link = $(this);
        current = link.parent().index();
        run(link, audio[0]);
    });
    audio[0].addEventListener('ended',function(e){
        current++;
        if(current == len){
            current = 0;
            link = playlist.find('a')[0];
        }else{
            link = playlist.find('a')[current];    
        }
        run($(link),audio[0]);
    });
}
function run(link, player){
        player.src = link.attr('href');
        par = link.parent();
        par.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        audio[0].load();
        audio[0].play();
}
</script>


    <audio id="audio" preload="auto" tabindex="0" controls="" type="audio/mpeg">
        <source type="audio/mp3" src="http://www.archive.org/download/bolero_69/Bolero.mp3">
        Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
    </audio>
    <ul id="playlist">
        <li class="active"><a href="http://www.archive.org/download/bolero_69/Bolero.mp3">Ravel Bolero</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.archive.org/download/MoonlightSonata_755/Beethoven-MoonlightSonata.mp3">Moonlight Sonata - Beethoven</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.archive.org/download/CanonInD_261/CanoninD.mp3">Canon in D Pachabel</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.archive.org/download/PatrikbkarlChamberSymph/PatrikbkarlChamberSymph_vbr_mp3.zip">patrikbkarl chamber symph</a></li>

    </ul>
```

Comment: What errors have you ran in to? We cannot help you without you providing errors, what doesn't work, what you've tried and such.

Comment: You need to show some more effort. What error messages do you get? How have you gone about to debug this script? This forum is not for **"why does this code not work"** type questions.

Comment: Do you have access to JQuery through this editor, since you're using it?
Check your dev-console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/474wkra0/)

Please check this demo.Are you trying to achieve this
    var audio;
    var playlist;
    var tracks;
    var current;

```
init();
function init(){
    current = 0;
    audio = $('audio');
    playlist = $('#playlist');
    tracks = playlist.find('li a');
    len = tracks.length - 1;
    audio[0].volume = .10;
    playlist.find('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        link = $(this);
        current = link.parent().index();
        run(link, audio[0]);
    });
    audio[0].addEventListener('ended',function(e){
        current++;
        if(current == len){
            current = 0;
            link = playlist.find('a')[0];
        }else{
            link = playlist.find('a')[current];    
        }
        run($(link),audio[0]);
    });
}
function run(link, player){
        player.src = link.attr('href');
        par = link.parent();
        par.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        audio[0].load();
        audio[0].play();
}
```